# Подключение c++ библиотеки в c#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

Имею библиотеку написанную на c++
`AVerCapAPI_Pro.h`

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  (c) Copyright AVerMedia Technologies, Inc. 2015. All Rights Reserved.
//
//      Module  :  AVerCapAPI_Pro.H
//      Abstract:  Header file for AVerCapAPI_Pro.DLL
//      Date    :  12/13/2017
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef _AVERCAPAPI_PRO_H_
#define _AVERCAPAPI_PRO_H_

#ifdef _X64_MACHINE
typedef __int64 LONGPTR;
#else
typedef long LONGPTR;
#endif

// error code
enum
{
    CAP_EC_SUCCESS                =  0,
    CAP_EC_INIT_DEVICE_FAILED     = -1,
    CAP_EC_DEVICE_IN_USE          = -2,
    CAP_EC_NOT_SUPPORTED          = -3,
    CAP_EC_INVALID_PARAM          = -4,
    CAP_EC_TIMEOUT                = -5,
    CAP_EC_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY      = -6,
    CAP_EC_UNKNOWN_ERROR          = -7,
    CAP_EC_ERROR_STATE            = -8,
    CAP_EC_HDCP_PROTECTED_CONTENT = -9
};

// device type
enum
{
    DEVICETYPE_SD  = 1,
    DEVICETYPE_HD  = 2,
    DEVICETYPE_ALL = 3
};

// video input source
enum
{
    VIDEOSOURCE_COMPOSITE = 0,
    VIDEOSOURCE_SVIDEO    = 1,
    VIDEOSOURCE_COMPONENT = 2,
    VIDEOSOURCE_HDMI      = 3,
    VIDEOSOURCE_VGA       = 4,
    VIDEOSOURCE_SDI       = 5,
    VIDEOSOURCE_ASI       = 6,
    VIDEOSOURCE_DVI       = 7
};

// audio input source
enum
{
    AUDIOSOURCE_NONE      = 0x00000000,
    AUDIOSOURCE_COMPOSITE = 0x00000001,
    AUDIOSOURCE_SVIDEO    = 0x00000002,
    AUDIOSOURCE_COMPONENT = 0x00000004,
    AUDIOSOURCE_HDMI      = 0x00000008,
    AUDIOSOURCE_VGA       = 0x00000010,
    AUDIOSOURCE_SDI       = 0x00000020,
    AUDIOSOURCE_ASI       = 0x00000040,
    AUDIOSOURCE_DVI       = 0x00000080,
    AUDIOSOURCE_DEFAULT   = 0xFFFFFFFF
};

// video format
enum
{                                       
    VIDEOFORMAT_NTSC = 0,
    VIDEOFORMAT_PAL  = 1,
    VIDEOFORMAT_ALL  = 2
};

//video Color Space
enum
{
    VIDEOCOLORSPACE_YV12 = 1,
    VIDEOCOLORSPACE_YUY2 = 2,
    VIDEOCOLORSPACE_V210 = 4,
    VIDEOCOLORSPACE_RGB24 = 8,
    VIDEOCOLORSPACE_RGB32 = 16,
};

// video resolution
enum
{                   
    VIDEORESOLUTION_640X480   = 0,              
    VIDEORESOLUTION_704X576   = 1,              
    VIDEORESOLUTION_720X480   = 2,              
    VIDEORESOLUTION_720X576   = 4,                  
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1920X1080 = 7,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_160X120   = 20, 
    VIDEORESOLUTION_176X144   = 21,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_240X176   = 22,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_240X180   = 23,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_320X240   = 24,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_352X240   = 25,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_352X288   = 26,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_640X240   = 27,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_640X288   = 28,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_720X240   = 29,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_720X288   = 30,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_80X60     = 31,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_88X72     = 32,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_128X96    = 33,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_640X576   = 34,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_180X120   = 37,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_180X144   = 38,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_360X240   = 39, 
    VIDEORESOLUTION_360X288   = 40,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_768X576   = 41,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_384x288   = 42,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_192x144   = 43,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1280X720  = 44,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1024X768  = 45,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1280X800  = 46, 
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1280X1024 = 47,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1440X900  = 48,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1600X1200 = 49,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1680X1050 = 50,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_800X600   = 51,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1280X768  = 52,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1360X768  = 53, 
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1152X864  = 54, 
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1280X960  = 55,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_702X576   = 56,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_720X400   = 57,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1152X900  = 58,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1360X1024 = 59,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1366X768  = 60,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1400X1050 = 61,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1440X480  = 62,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1440X576  = 63,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1600X900  = 64, 
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1920X1200 = 65,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1440X1080 = 66,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1600X1024 = 67,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_3840X2160 = 68,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1152X768  = 69,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_176X120  = 70,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_704X480  = 71,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1792X1344= 72,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1856X1392= 73,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_1920X1440= 74,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_2048X1152= 75,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_2560X1080= 76,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_2560X1440= 77,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_2560X1600= 78,
    VIDEORESOLUTION_4096X2160= 79,
};

// video adjustment property
enum
{
    VIDEOPROCAMPPROPERTY_BRIGHTNESS = 0,
    VIDEOPROCAMPPROPERTY_CONTRAST   = 1,
    VIDEOPROCAMPPROPERTY_HUE        = 2,
    VIDEOPROCAMPPROPERTY_SATURATION = 3
};

// deinterlace mode
enum
{
    DEINTERLACE_NONE  = 0,
    DEINTERLACE_WEAVE = 1,
    DEINTERLACE_BOB   = 2,
    DEINTERLACE_BLEND = 3
};

// downscale mode
enum
{
    DSMODE_NONE       = 0,
    DSMODE_HALFHEIGHT = 1,
    DSMODE_HALFWIDTH  = 2,
    DSMODE_HALFBOTH   = 3,
    DSMODE_CUSTOM     = 5
};

// overlay settings
enum
{
    OVERLAY_TEXT  = 0,
    OVERLAY_TIME  = 1,
    OVERLAY_IMAGE = 2,
    OVERLAY_MOSAIC= 6,
    OVERLAY_MARQUEE=7
};

// font size
enum
{
    FONTSIZE_SMALL = 0,
    FONTSIZE_BIG   = 1
};

// time format
enum
{
    FORMAT_TIMEONLY    = 0,
    FORMAT_DATEANDTIME = 1
};

// alignment
enum
{
    ALIGNMENT_LEFT   = 0,
    ALIGNMENT_CENTER = 1,
    ALIGNMENT_RIGHT  = 2
};

// video frame/field capture settings
enum
{
    CT_SEQUENCE_FIELD = 0,
    CT_SEQUENCE_FRAME = 1
};

// video save type
enum
{
    ST_BMP            = 0,
    ST_JPG            = 1,
    ST_AVI            = 2,
    ST_CALLBACK       = 3,
    ST_WAV            = 4,
    ST_PNG            = 6,
    ST_MPG            = 7,
    ST_MP4            = 8,
    ST_TIFF           = 9,
    ST_CALLBACK_RGB24 = 10,
    ST_CALLBACK_ARGB  = 11,
    ST_TS             = 13
};


// video capture duration settings
enum 
{
    DURATION_TIME  = 1,
    DURATION_COUNT = 2
};

// video enhance
enum
{
    VIDEOENHANCE_NONE    = 0, 
    VIDEOENHANCE_NORMAL  = 1,  
    VIDEOENHANCE_SPLIT   = 2, 
    VIDEOENHANCE_COMPARE = 3
};

// video mirror
enum
{
    VIDEOMIRROR_NONE       = 0,
    VIDEOMIRROR_HORIZONTAL = 1,
    VIDEOMIRROR_VERTICAL   = 2,
    VIDEOMIRROR_BOTH       = 3                  
};

// audio bit rate
enum AudioBitRate
{
    AUDIOBITRATE_NONE = -1,
    AUDIOBITRATE_96   = 0,
    AUDIOBITRATE_112  = 1,
    AUDIOBITRATE_128  = 2,
    AUDIOBITRATE_144  = 3,
    AUDIOBITRATE_160  = 4,
    AUDIOBITRATE_176  = 5,
    AUDIOBITRATE_192  = 6,
    AUDIOBITRATE_224  = 7,
    AUDIOBITRATE_256  = 8,
    AUDIOBITRATE_288  = 9,
    AUDIOBITRATE_320  = 10,
    AUDIOBITRATE_352  = 11,
    AUDIOBITRATE_384  = 12,
    AUDIOBITRATE_64   = 13,
    AUDIOBITRATE_32   = 14
};

// video rotate
enum
{
    VIDEOROTATE_NONE = 0,
    VIDEOROTATE_CW90 = 1,   
    VIDEOROTATE_CCW90 = 2
};

// encoder type
enum
{
    ENCODERTYPE_MPEGAUDIO = 0x00000001,
    ENCODERTYPE_H264      = 0x00000002,
    ENCODERTYPE_MPEG2AAC  = 0x00000004
};


// capture type
enum 
{   
    CT_CALLBACK_MPEGAUDIO = 0x00000001,
    CT_CALLBACK_H264      = 0x00000002,
    CT_CALLBACK_TS        = 0x00000004,
    CT_FILE_TS            = 0x01000000,
    CT_FILE_MP4           = 0x02000000,
    CT_CALLBACK_MPEG2AAC  = 0x00000008
}; 

// sample type
enum
{
    SAMPLETYPE_NULL         = 0x00,
    SAMPLETYPE_RAWVIDEO     = 0x01,              // lpSampleInfo using VIDEO_SAMPLE_INFO
    SAMPLETYPE_PCMAUDIO     = 0x02,              // lpSampleInfo using AUDIO_SAMPLE_INFO
    SAMPLETYPE_TS           = 0x10,              // lpSampleInfo using NULL
    SAMPLETYPE_ES_H264      = 0x20,              // lpSampleInfo using NULL
    SAMPLETYPE_ES_H265      = 0x21,              // lpSampleInfo using NULL
    SAMPLETYPE_ES_MPEG4AAC  = 0x30,              // lpSampleInfo using NULL
    SAMPLETYPE_ES_MPEGAUDIO = 0x31,              // lpSampleInfo using AUDIO_SAMPLE_INFO
    SAMPLETYPE_ES_MPEG2AAC  = 0x32               // lpSampleInfo using NULL
};

// video renderer
enum
{
    VIDEORENDERER_DEFAULT = 0,              //VMR9
    VIDEORENDERER_VMR7    = 1,
    VIDEORENDERER_VMR9    = 2,
    VIDEORENDERER_EVR     = 3               //vista, win7, server 2008
};

// image quality
enum
{
    IMAGEQUALITY_BEST   = 0,
    IMAGEQUALITY_NORMAL = 1,
    IMAGEQUALITY_LOW    = 2
};

// image type
enum
{
    IMAGETYPE_BMP  = 1,
    IMAGETYPE_JPG  = 2,
    IMAGETYPE_PNG  = 3,
    IMAGETYPE_TIFF = 4
};

// event
enum
{
    EVENT_CAPTUREIMAGE = 1,                   //CAPTUREIMAGE_NOTIFY_INFO
    EVENT_CHECKCOPP    = 2,                   //LONG
    EVENT_SPLITFILE    = 3                    //LPWSTR
};

// copp error code
enum
{
    COPP_ERR_UNKNOWN                                  = 0x80000001,
    COPP_ERR_NO_COPP_HW                               = 0x80000002,
    COPP_ERR_NO_MONITORS_CORRESPOND_TO_DISPLAY_DEVICE = 0x80000003,
    COPP_ERR_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN_FAILED                 = 0x80000004,
    COPP_ERR_STATUS_LINK_LOST                         = 0x80000005,
    COPP_ERR_NO_HDCP_PROTECTION_TYPE                  = 0x80000006,
    COPP_ERR_HDCP_REPEATER                            = 0x80000007,
    COPP_ERR_HDCP_PROTECTED_CONTENT                   = 0x80000008,
    COPP_ERR_GET_CRL_FAILED                           = 0x80000009
};

// RC mode
enum
{
    RCMODE_CBR        = 0x01,       //Constant bitrate 
    RCMODE_VBR        = 0x02,       //Variable bitrate
    RCMODE_ABR        = 0x03,       //Average bitrate
    RCMODE_STRICT_ABR = 0x04        //Strict average bitrate
};

// aspect ratio mode
enum
{
    ASPECT_RATIO_AUTO   = 0,  //Automatic mode (according to the resolution is automatically set to closer to 4:3 or 16:9)
    ASPECT_RATIO_4_3    = 1,  //4：3 mode 
    ASPECT_RATIO_16_9   = 2,  //16：9 mode 
    ASPECT_RATIO_CUSTOM = 4,  //Actual display AspectRatio (user set as the actual display AspectRatio, internal conversion to pixel scale is set to Codec. The actual working mode of the Codec ASPECT RATIO PAR)
    ASPECT_RATIO_PIXEL  = 5   //Always be current the actual number of pixels than (the actual working mode of the Codec ASPECT thewire PAR 1:1)
};
// HWVA
enum
{
    HWVA_ENCODER_H264           = 0x01,
};

//mode
enum
{
    MODE_HW = 0,
    MODE_SW = 1
};
```

Часть кода библиотеки удалил. Имею `dll`. Вопрос, как правильно ее подключить?

## UPDATE

Примерно, понял, как подключить к c# проекту, но не понимаю как правильно воспользоваться оттуда функциями. Вот, например есть функция:

```
LONG WINAPI AVerGetDeviceName(DWORD dwDeviceIndex, LPWSTR szDeviceName)
```

Вызов примерно будет такой:

```
[DllImport("TestLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern ????;
```

На знаках ? я так понимаю должна быть данная функция. Как она будет выглядеть?

Comment: dll есть, в sdk

Comment: данными функциями спокойно пользуюсь в c++